# Plugin or tool for eclipse that can show the connectivity between tables in a graphical pic format

Tags: java, database, eclipse, db2

I use to connect to database through eclipse database explorer perspective and I can see all the tales of my database ,Please advise is there any plugin or tool by which let say I have connectivity between three different tables through primary key and foreign key so that I can show graphically that how these three tables are connected as I have to put it into slide , although I have the query but end user will grasp the pic more clearly.

please advise .

Comment: Make an entity-relationship diagram? It isn't that hard...

Answer (score 1):

That will probably not be doable in Eclipse with DB2. [SchemaSpy](http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/) will do exactly what you want. I have used it and it works if there's something to work on (fks set or sane naming scheme) in the database. Don't worry about the tool being a bit archaic, it generates good looking output.